# SQL Table to matrix

Tags: java, sql, h2

I have the following data in a SQL table.

```
Entity1 | Entity2
A , B
A , C 
B , D
```

I need to convert it to

```
A, B, C, D 
0, 1, 1, 0 
0, 0, 0, 1
0, 0, 0, 0 
0, 0, 0, 0
```

The first line is the list of all entities. 
The second and subsequent lines list the dependency of elements.

Since A depends on B and C the second line is

```
0, 1, 1, 0
```

Since B depends on D only, the third line is

```
0, 0, 0, 1
```

I am working with H2 and Java. It will help if someone could suggest something using SQL and Java.

Comment: each line stands for another entity order by ASC ? (a is the first row b is second c is third...?) and also, what is the range of it? a,b,c,d or all the alphabetic letters

Comment: - Each line stands for one entity. - The first line, i.e the header of the matrix, has the same order horizontally, as the order of the rows below, vertically - The A, B etc represents nodes and they will have proper names. - Assume that the number of nodes is about 500 or so.

Answer (score 0):

This simulation of your situation is giving your desired result

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (Entity1 VARCHAR(1),entity2 VARCHAR(1))
    INSERT INTO @table VALUES ('A','B'),('A','C'),('B','D')
    DECLARE @i INT=0
    DECLARE @j INT=0
    DECLARE @val VARCHAR(150)=','
    DECLARE @sel VARCHAR(5000)=''
    DECLARE @cnt INT
    SET @cnt=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT entity1 Entity FROM @table UNION SELECT entity2 FROM @table) AS ct)
    WHILE @i<@cnt
    BEGIN
        set @val = @val +',''' + (SELECT TOP(1) LEAD(entity,@i,0) over (ORDER BY entity) FROM (SELECT entity1 Entity FROM @table UNION SELECT entity2 FROM @table) AS nt)+''''
        SET @i=@i+1
        PRINT replace(@val,',,','')
    END
    SET @sel='SELECT ' + replace(@val,',,','')

    SET @i=0
    SET @val=','
    WHILE @i<@cnt
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @firstEntity VARCHAR(1)=(SELECT TOP(1) LEAD(entity,@i,0) over (ORDER BY entity) FROM (SELECT entity1 Entity FROM @table UNION SELECT entity2 FROM @table) AS nt)
        PRINT @firstEntity
        WHILE @j<@cnt
        BEGIN   
            DECLARE @lastEntity VARCHAR(1)=(SELECT TOP(1) LEAD(entity,@j,0) over (ORDER BY entity) FROM (SELECT entity1 Entity FROM @table UNION SELECT entity2 FROM @table) AS nt)
            PRINT @lastEntity
            IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @table WHERE Entity1=@firstEntity AND entity2=@lastEntity)
            BEGIN
                SET @val=@val+',''1'''
            END
            ELSE
                BEGIN
                    SET @val=@val+',''0'''
                END

                SET @j=@j+1
        END
        SET @sel= @sel+' UNION ALL SELECT ' + replace(@val,',,','')
        SET @val=','
        SET @j=0
        SET @i=@i+1
    END
    PRINT @sel
    EXEC (@sel)
```

Answer (score 0):

Implementation in Java (without comma and Brackets)

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    List<ArrayList> table = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();
    ArrayList<String> row1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    row1.add("A");
    row1.add("B");
    table.add(row1);
    ArrayList<String> row2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    row2.add("C");
    row2.add("A");
    table.add(row2);
    ArrayList<String> row3 = new ArrayList<String>();
    row3.add("B");
    row3.add("D");
    table.add(row3);
    ArrayList<String> row4 = new ArrayList<String>();
    row4.add("D");
    row4.add("A");
    table.add(row4);
    ArrayList<String> row5 = new ArrayList<String>();
    row5.add("D");
    row5.add("E");
    table.add(row5);
    ArrayList<String> entity = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i = 0 ; i < table.size();i++){
        for(int j = 0 ; j < table.get(i).size();j++){
            String temp = (String) table.get(i).get(j);

            //to get list of entities for the first Line
            if(!entity.contains(temp)){
                entity.add(temp);System.out.print(temp);}       
        }
    }   

    System.out.println();   
    boolean flag = false;
    for(int x =0 ; x < entity.size(); x++){
        for(int z = 0 ; z < entity.size() ; z++){

            for(int i = 0 ; i < table.size();i++){


                    if(table.get(i).get(0) == entity.get(x) & table.get(i).get(1) == entity.get(z))
                    {System.out.print("1");flag = true;break;}


            }   //i
            if(flag == false){System.out.print("0");}
            flag = false;
        }//z
        System.out.println();
    }//x


}
```